# How to make shortcut to automatically open specific option from group policy (gpedit.msc)

Tags: windows, taskbar, group-policy

I want to be able to single click on shortcut and automatically set Enabled/Disabled policy I want. So how can I do that without malinkg *.lnk file to point to c:\Windows\system32\gpedit.msc and through that link to go and find desired option I wish to modify? In other words, is there some possible switch I can use to automatically redirect gpedit.msc to for ex. : User Configuration/Adiministrative Templates/Start Menu and Taskbar/Prevent usesrs from resizing taskbar/(Disabled/Enabled)

Answer (score 0):

I've found some relevant link... I'll try to examine provided solutions...

[change-group-policy-gpedit-msc-setting-shortcut](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/130888-change-group-policy-gpedit-msc-setting-shortcut.html)